# My navigation bar is not moving up when scrolling UITableView with background image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have this view hierarchy on a view embedded in a UINavigationController:

[image]

When I scroll the UITableView the navigation bar is not moving up (the title is not becoming smaller) it stays like this:

[image]

If I remove the image view as background view everything works well.

[image]

My navigation is configured like this:

```
navigationItem.title = "Title here"
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

A project demonstrating the problem is available here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/181Aggala2ZfGN0lDjEtHWg0vobkM0iJc/view?usp=sharing

I already tried to change the insets of the tableview but it didn't work.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: navigationController?.navigationBar.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, to make large title fonts work as you want them to, the `UIScrollView` or any of its subclass needs to be the first element in the view hierarchy.

To fix your problem, you can try setting the background image to be the background of the `UITableView` directly.

**Edit:** Okay soo according to your comment you want a background behind everything including navigation bar. There is one way of achieving this and that is to subclass your `UINavigationController` and inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let image = UIImage(named: "wallpaper")
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
   imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

   imageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
   //this below part is important. Make sure to set it to 0 otherwise it will cover everything else
   view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)
}
```

And then make sure your `UIViewController` containing the `UITableView` has a clear color for the `UIView` and remove the background image from that `UIViewController`

Comment: But I need the image to cover the entire screen (I need to see this image behind the navigation bar and the table view). 

If I add the image as background image, I only will see it behind the table view. 

And if I put the table view behind the navigation bar, the contents of the table view will also be behind the navigation bar and only need the image to be behind it.

See here: 
https://imgur.com/a/8KVyHMf

Comment: @user1539434 please see the edit. It should solve your problem